# Draw common outline for two shapes, each in a different UIView - ObjC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have two `UIView`s. Each `UIView` has a shape drawn using `drawRect` method. I need to draw the common outline for both these shapes. How can I do this?

This question is about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941042/common-outline-for-two-shapes-drawn-in-drawrect-objectivec) is about two shapes in a single `UIView`. Mine is about shapes in diferent `UIView`s.

Answer (score 0):

If by common outline, you mean, the area that both shapes share (intersect) relative to parent `UIView` for both of those `UIViews` which contain these shapes independently.

Then you need to implement some kind of method to find out the shared region (area) and then draw the outline using a third transparent view(BG Color's alpha -> 0.0f).

As far as I know, **you can't create a shared context instance** from **`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`** to draw simultaneously on more than one view.

Or If you mean the boundary of both views, without the middle shared line, 
you have to get context reference from the **parent `UIView`** of the two `UIViews`,

**Associate it to both `UIViews` objects using properties**, 
then draw in both of them using same context reference independently.

Comment: Yes, I need the boundary without a line in the middle. I want the shapes to appear as one.

Comment: Then go with this part :- You have to get context reference from the parent UIView of the two UIViews,

Associate it to both UIViews objects using properties & then draw in both of them using same context reference independently.

Comment: I am sorry for being a nuisance, but I don't get what you are saying. Can you please provide a sample code of any sort?